# Some questions about Twistor Space of a closed $4$-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, 4-manifolds, twistor-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold of dimension $4$. We denote its twistor space, the space of almost complex structures on the tangent bundle $TM$ by $Z\xrightarrow{\pi}M$. At any point the fibre is isomorphic to $S^2$. Now this can be seen as $S(\Lambda_+^2M),$i.e., the sphere bundle of the self-dual two forms on $M$. Self dual means $*\omega=\omega$.

$1.$ I want to know how this description works; i.e., given a self dual two form at a point $m\in M,$ how do we get an almost complex structure on $T_m M?$

$2.$ Is it possible to induce a metric on $Z$ from $M$, if yes how?

$3.$ Once we put a metric on $Z$ and take the corresponding Levi-Civita connection we get a splitting of the tangent bundle in terms of horizontal and vertical vectors:
\begin{equation*}
TZ=TV\oplus TH\cong TV\oplus \pi^*(TM)
\end{equation*}
Does this give a reduction of the structure group $SO(6)$ to $SO(4)\times SO(2)?$

Comment: Here is some thoughts. For the first question, given a self-dual 2-form $\omega$ and a vector field $v$, the contraction $\iota_v\omega$ defines a 1-form, then using Riemannian metric to get another vector field, this will be an almost complex structure. For the second question, the Riemannian metric on $M$ induces a Riemnian metric on $T^{\star}M$ also on $\Lambda_+^2M$, one could think the twistor space is a submanifold of $\Lambda_+^2M$.

Comment: @SanJohn thanks for the comment, would you please explain a bit how this construction gives an almost complex structure.

Comment: Hint: choose a orthnormal frame $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ and write $\omega=e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4$. To check this.

Comment: @Partha A few points of confusion: Presumably you're interested in an *oriented* Riemannian manifold $(M.g,\mu)$, where $\mu$ is a Riemann volume form, since otherwise the Hodge star is not well defined. Your definition of $Z$ also doesn't match your description: The space of almost complex structures in *not* an $S^2$-bundle; perhaps you mean the space of complex structures compatible with $g$ and $\mu$? Also, in your third question you ask about structure groups, but on which bundle? What $SO(6)$-structure are you referring to?

Comment: @Kajelad yes you are right, I meant compatible with the metric and the volume form. So the structure group is about the tangent bundle. $TZ=Z\times_{SO(6)}\mathbb{R}^6$. Using the splitting can we reduce this to $SO(4)\times SO(2)$ or even $SO(4)\times U(1)$? This would also imply that the connection form would take values in $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(4)\oplus \mathfrak{so}(2)$ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, $\Lambda^2$ can be regarded as skew-adjoint endomorphisms of the tangent bundle. Then for any $J\in \Lambda^-$ at a given point $x\in M$, i.e. unit anti-self-dual 2-form, we have $$J^* = -J$$, and hence $$J^2 = -I$$, which gives a complex structure on $T_x M$.
2. Yes. We have the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ on $TM$, which could induce connections on all its tensor bundles, i.e. $S TM$, $ST^*M$, $\Lambda TM$, $\Lambda T^*M$ etc.
3. Yes, it's from your argument.